# Getting "Signature fields not well formed." while uploading file using Azure REST api

Tags: azure-media-services

While following steps given in a documentation on link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-get-started) for uploading video file on starage account, i am getting below error.
I am using api returned in path property to upload blob content which is returned in api called for creating SAS locator url.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:26b8138d-0001-006c-72e3-9ed651000000
Time:2017-03-17T05:55:44.0536797Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Comment: your sas header is wrong

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. Can you please explain with an example.

Comment: This question cannot possibly be answered without more details. At the very least you have to provide the URL which you request before you get the error message above.